# Deff function scilab

Tags: function, scilab, bisection

Can anyone please explain me how exactly to use the deff function on scilab? I'm trying to code the process of calculating a root of an equation through the bisection method but the user must provide the function, so it is supposed to work with almost any function.

Answer (score 0):

deff is a function that can be used inside a Scilab program to define a Scilab function . It is an alternative to the 
function ...
endfunction
construct

It is particularly useful to create a new function which depends on some states of the calling Scilab function

Trivial example:

```
function y=foo(funname,b)
  deff("y=foot(a)","y="+funname+"(a)^2")
  y=foot(b)
endfunction
foo("sqrt",33)
foo("sin",%pi)
```